# TOAD SQL for SYBASE ASE- Executing Multiple Select Statements

Tags: sql, sap-ase, toad

I have a script like below that when I run, the result output separates the two `Select` statements into 2 result sets. How do I run so that the output of the second `Select` statement is appended onto the bottom of the first? I've checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698855/run-multiple-sql-statements-using-only-execute-in-toad) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170792/toad-for-oracle-how-to-execute-multiple-statements?rq=1) but they're for `Oracle` and don't seem to work for me with `Sybase-ASE`.

```
SELECT " ", BizDate, " ", getdate(), "North America"
FROM #BizDateTemp

Select *
From SalesTable
Where BizDate = getdate()
```

Desired result:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|   | 12/13/2016|     |  12/13/2016 | North America | 
-----------------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------------
|   Sale Item   |   QTY   |   PRICE   |   BizDate   |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   plankton    |  1,000  |  $60,000  |  12/13/2016 |
```

What happens now:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|   | 12/13/2016|     |  12/13/2016 | North America | 
-----------------------------------------------------
```

separated from :

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|   Sale Item   |   QTY   |   PRICE   |   BizDate   |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   plankton    |  1,000  |  $60,000  |  12/13/2016 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new "Toad for SAP Solutions" can display multiple query results in one single windows:

1) To enable view of all Result Sets in one Tab:
Check Options | Database | Script results | Enable all results view

2) Run you query

3) Review all (or the selected Result sets) in one Result Sets tab: 
Left-click and hold Shift to select more than one Result sets of your script. 
Select All results to review all in one tab.

Comment: I have Toad for Sybase 2.1.0.2921. I don't see "Enable all results view" as an option. I can either do "All in one tab" or "One tab per query" for Script Result Grouping. I'm currently in "All in one tab". I tried the shift click but it didn't work.

Comment: as I said this is only in the new version of TOAD for Sybase called TOAD for SAP Solutions. You can download the freeware version and test it.

Comment: I asked the Toad people this question and they explained that Toad for SAP is the newer version of Toad for Sybase. I would need to move to the newer version. Thanks!